# how to start a new intent from a service class (android)

Tags: android, service, alarm, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to start an Activity from a Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456034/how-to-start-an-activity-from-a-service)

apologies for my terminology in advance I am very new to android programming.

What i am trying to do:

i am trying to create an alarm clock application.

What i have so far:

so far i have a class that starts an alarm service after 5 seconds (this works fine). then when this service class starts i want it to start another class (called AlarmRinging) but this is where I come unstuck.

Any answers or avenues to check out would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**android.app.Service** is descendant of **android.app.Context** so you can use **startActivity** directly. However since you start this outside any activity you need to set **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** flag on the intent.

For example:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(this, MyActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

where **this** is your service.

Comment: brilliant It works Thank you. is there anyway of sending extras from my 1st class to the service class?

Comment: See this link http://android-coding.blogspot.com/


In service Override onStart() -- you receive the Intent as a parameter.