# Android - start Activity from Service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to start an Activity from a Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456034/how-to-start-an-activity-from-a-service)

I have service, which checks app versions and if there is new, it should prompt my fully functioning installation intent. My question is - how to start intent on actual screen from service?

Edit: I have thought of int status, i will compare actual version installed and version on the web. If there is newer version, I will set status=1. And for each intent in my app i add if clause:

```
If(status==1){
// prompt installation intent
}
```

but how to get this "status" which is declared and inicialized in service class?

Thanks

Comment: You appear to be using the term 'intent' when perhaps 'activity' would be more accurate.

Comment: OK, Edited - but still no progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask two questions.

1. It seems possible to launch an Activity from a service.
   [android start activity from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service)

   However I would strongly recommend you used the Alert mechanism to inform the user an update was ready, rather than 'pulling the rug' with a complete change of context.
2. Regarding your 'status' variable, you may consider storing this in SharedPreferences which will be accessible in both the service and the activities.

   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Activity I will be calling is made from alert with update request, so there is no problem. Great!