# Pop up dialog in Android home screen

Tags: android, dialog

Is it possible to show pop up dialog (AlertDialog) in home screen on the android device via services?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could create an `Activity` with the `Theme.Dialog` theme. In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file add the theme to the activity, like this:

```
<activity android:name=".DialogActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
```

From your service simply start this `Activity`. You will have to start the activity with the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag. See [How to start an Activity from a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456034/how-to-start-an-activity-from-a-service)

Comment: Aki,Dallas: I have used this Theme.Dialog and works successfully. Thanks for that but i have one question what to do to remove this dialog box on button click???

Comment: Call finish() in the onclicklistner of the button

Answer (score 4):

Does anyone needs option, "android:launchMode="singleInstance", when pop activity in the broadcast receiver or Service??
Without this option, my app started automatically and pop MyDialogActivity above it.
And then, something happened wrong. (My app has the Main Activity with auto-login function. When the other new Activity started automatically, MyDialogActivity is hided by it.)

So, this is my sample xml code.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MyDialogActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
    <activity
```

I hope someone needs my comments. :)

Comment: have been stumbling on the internet for hours, setting the launchMode helps, thx.

Answer (score 2):

You can not create dialog from service but we have one alternative solution is that You can create `dialog activity` and start that activity from your service

**You can set Theme of activity as dialog by below way**

```
<activity android:name=".MyDialogActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create **CustomDialog** As Activity

add to manifest

```
<activity android:name=".view.activity.CustomDialog"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
        android:theme="@style/AlertDialogTheme"
        />
```

add Style AlertDialogTheme to style.xml

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog.Alert.Bridge">

</style>
```