# How to handle incoming intents from external applications in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Some services vary between Android and iPhone, for example floating widget, widget on the home screen, can I make them using flutter

Can I view a dialog on the home screen like this example?

[image]

update
thank everyone answer, but I need how to get it in Flutter

Comment: Try using a transparent activity :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-do-i-create-a-transparent-activity-on-android

Comment: Sorry but you can't do it in Flutter because doing in Flutter means doing for both platform and since iOS doesn't support that, you simply can't use Flutter alone for it, you'll have to do it using method channel natively.

Comment: I want this to be only for Android, i use Platform.isAndroid

Comment: Some services vary between Android and iPhone, for example floating widget, widget on home screen, can i make them using flutter

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can show that

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this)
                                .setTitle("Alert")
                                .setMessage("Alert Message")
                                .setCancelable(false)
                                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        //Here you can do whatever you want to do on click 
                                    }
                                }).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you can't do it in iOS, however in Android, you can, all you need to do is write platform specific code.

You could create an `Activity` with the `Theme.Dialog` theme. In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file add the theme to the activity, like this:

```
<activity android:name=".DialogActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></activity>
```

From your service simply start this `Activity`. You will have to start the activity with the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag. See [How to start an Activity from a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456034/how-to-start-an-activity-from-a-service)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7592253/6618622)