# Show dialog every time turn on phone

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I need to show custom dialog that's gite data from Api and display it in this dialog on the screen every time the user open his phone from lock it.

I know how to setup the Api call and All these thing, but I don't know how can I show the dialog screen every time the user open his phone.
And also How can I show the dialog windows screen over homepage of the phone. Thank you.

Comment: You can detect phone unlock by using the broadcast receiver https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446202/android-detect-phone-unlock-event-not-screen-on

Comment: Thank you. But How can I show the dialog windows screen over homepage of the phone?

Comment: @dadCoder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591670/pop-up-dialog-in-android-home-screen

Comment: You can detect phone unlock by using  broadcast receiver and than on receive you have to inflate the dialog view on window manager... This way you can achieve your task