# Activity within a service

Tags: android, android-activity

I am looking into displaying an activity when the service is first started so i created a new class put some code an xml but the R.id references are not beeing resolved and what can i do next ?

Comment: can u please put the code.... clean the project and run again or there might a error in the manifest file .. but not sure about it

Comment: so, you're starting the service first and then you want to start an Activity from within your Service? as far as I know, this would not work... why don't you do it the other way round?

Comment: Do you want to start an activity from service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this...

```
public class TestService extends Service {

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
            Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), myActivity.class);
    dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);
    }
}
```

[android start activity from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606596/android-start-activity-from-service)

[How to start an Activity from a Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456034/how-to-start-an-activity-from-a-service)