# Start a phone call from a service

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write an android service, to amongst other things, start a phone call. I have got the service to do other things: listen on network, accept a connection, process text and respond with text. I am now trying to set up a call.

So far I have, the bit to set up the call is it the extra unnecessary {}, when I paste the code in the extra {} in to the activity that starts this service, the call is set up. The only thing I see different is the context. So what am I doing wrong?

```
public class Service extends android.app.Service {

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {  
    {
        android.content.Intent intent2 = 
                new android.content.Intent(
                    android.content.Intent.ACTION_CALL, 
                    android.net.Uri.parse("tel:012345556789"));
        this.startActivity(intent2);
    }       
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

stack

```
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
    ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread$ServiceArgsData) line: 2673 
    ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ServiceArgsData) line: 141    
    ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1331  
    ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 137 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5039    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 793  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 560 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: I tried invokling call from my service in my application and it worked. I invoke the call when someone shakes the mobile

Comment: Added `intent2.setFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` before startActivity. Now no error, but also no anything.

Comment: I gave you downvote because you don't accept others ideas.

Comment: I tried your idea, it seems to work but leaves the question, what are services for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that starting an activity from a service is a special case, you need a flag, probably to stop accidental activity start. I got the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3456099/537980

```
{
    android.content.Intent intent2 = 
            new android.content.Intent(
                android.content.Intent.ACTION_CALL, 
                android.net.Uri.parse("tel:012345556789"));
    intent2.setFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //Add this line, if starting an activity from a service.
    this.startActivity(intent2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call phone this is code :

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
        startActivity(callIntent);
```

But better approach is using this in new thread in activity - code snippet :

```
Thread thread = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {

Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
        startActivity(callIntent);

    }
};

thread.start();
```

You must have : `CALL_PHONE` permission in manifest.

I hope I helped

Comment: From what I understand this is equivalent, just a separate call to setData, instead of putting it as constructor arg. Tried it anyway and it made no difference. Note mine works from the activity that starts the service, so permission are correct, code is correct (at least in the context of an activity)

Comment: why do you paste this code to service, to onStartCommand method ?

Comment: The place I want it is in a thread that is started by onStartCommand, but I made it simpler to put in the question. Is your comment about the pointlessness of it be in synchronous, or is there some thing else I did wrong?

Comment: Make this in new thread, but in activity ! I added for you code exaple

Comment: If I put it in an activity will it not be killed when the activity is not in focus. (I assume that services are for running code when an activity is not active/visible.

Comment: -1 as just a re-factor of code in question, and telling me to put code in an activity (The question states I need a service).