# Loading GUI in **(full screen mode) from android Service

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I ve created android service which auto starts in boot.

1. i have a full screen activity
2. i need to open it when the service find the condition true.

as a example{

Service countdown a timer from 0. and make it ++ .  when timer ==100 i wanna load my fullscreen        GUI and make the timer again = 0 timer ++ and when timer ==10 dispose the old ui and again when  it reachs 100 again the same process.

}

ive created service and ui.
service working fine. but ui is not loading i ve used a toast to check the timer.

ive used below code from stackoverflow but not working

`Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(this, MyActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);`

source:[How to start an Activity from a Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456034/how-to-start-an-activity-from-a-service)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3607934/2931489

Comment: Its not working i am testing on kitkat :(

Comment: So what's the error ? Your app gona crash or what is happnng???
Perticular in this code... is this still not showing GUI?

Comment: its not loading having the unfortunately stopped error.

Comment: do you have a sample package?
which launch GUI using service.
GUI must be a fullscreen one.