# How to show share intent from service class android

Tags: android, android-intent, service, share

I have a service class.I need to share my few details through Facebook,whatsapp,gmail,yahoo etc.But when i tried share intent i getting an error

> android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from
>   outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
>   flag. Is this really what you want?

Below is my code

```
shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain"); 
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share via"));
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Log.e("clicked","clicked>>>>>>share");
```

Please give me a solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to start an Activity from a Service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456034/how-to-start-an-activity-from-a-service)

Comment: Calling `startActivity()` from a `Service` is a significant code smell. Why are you doing this?

Comment: @CommonsWare i have to share some test on gmail,Facebook etc.So on the service class there is a layout.When i click on the share button i need to show the list of apps.\

Comment: @DamianJeżewski: i dont want to start a new activity.I just want to show the share option like(share via Facebook,gmail,yahoo etc)

Comment: @Debugger I exactly know what you'd like to achieve. The thing is that linked question contains answer for your question and also some additional info that explains what happens under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

> Below is my code

Call `addFlags()` *before* `startActivity()`.

> So on the service class there is a layout

That is atypical for a service.

Comment: @Debugger: Then Android thinks that you are not calling `addFlags()` before `startActivity()`.