# Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) - Launch Activity when user clicks the notification with extras

Tags: android, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm trying to open a specific activity when the user clicks the notification, when the app is in the background, with some extra parameters. I'm using the `click_action` and it's working fine, the app opens the desired Activity.

Now I need the server to pass an extra parameter, an `id`, to this Activity so I can present the desired details associated with the notification. Like an e-mail application, that when we click on the notification opens the details of that specif email.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you share some code? I have a similar thing in my app but I'm using GCM. In the service that receives the notifications, I simply add a string extra to the Intent and use that to see which fragment I should open.

Comment: I don't need any help, my app works :) good for you that you've fixed it

Comment: Have you solved it? I am fetching same issue. I starting the targetActivity but didn't get extras from intent. Have you any solution?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Ok, I have found the solution.

This is the json that I'm sending from the server to the app

```
{
  "registration_ids": [
    "XXX",
    ...
  ],
  "data": {
    "id_offer": "41"
  },
  "notification": {
    "title": "This is the Title",
    "text": "Hello I'm a notification",
    "icon": "ic_push",
    "click_action": "ACTIVITY_XPTO"
  }
}
```

At the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityXPTO"
    android:screenOrientation="sensor"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="ACTIVITY_XPTO" />        
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When the app is closed or in background and the user clicks on the notification it opens my ActivityXPTO, to retrieve the id_offer I only need to do

```
public class ActivityXPTO extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...

        String idOffer = "";

        Intent startingIntent = getIntent();
        if (startingIntent != null) {
            idOffer = startingIntent.getStringExtra("id_offer"); // Retrieve the id
        }

        getOfferDetails(idOffer);
    }

    ...
}
```

That's it...

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37554274/open-app-on-firebase-notification-received-fcm/37626817#37626817

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. Using your way I starting the targetActivity but didn't get extras from intent. Have you any solution?

Comment: Hi @Md.SajedulKarim, do you have an example of the json you are sending from the server? You have to add the extras inside the "data" object of your json.

Comment: this worked for me too. if i want to open a particular page then what i have to do. see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44797486/open-specific-page-using-firebase-api

Answer (score 0):

Add addition information to Intent that you use to start Activity, and in activity in method onCreate use getIntent().getExtras() to use them. For example:

Starting activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, TargetActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("extraName", "extraValue"); 
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

In activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String value = bundle.getString("extraName");
    ....
}
```

Comment: It's not me who is starting the Activity. This is taken care by the system. The app is in background or closed.