# Unable to see cloud tab in FCM console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

I am trying to setup Firebase cloud messaging in my app. I created the project in Firebase console(I created a new project and did not import a previously created gcm project). I was able to successfully setup the project and have it running in app and receive sample notifications from notifications tab in firebase console.

While trying to send data messages via API https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send, I am getting unauthorized (401) response. Turns out I used the web key available in google-services.json, I need to use the server key from the cloud messaging tab mentioned in post ([Firebase 401 unauthorized error FCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37633188/firebase-401-unauthorized-error-fcm)).

I am unable to see the cloud tab in the project settings.[image: firebase project settings]
how can I enable the cloud tab for my project and why cant I see the clouds tab under project settings in firebase console?

Thanks,
P

Comment: Hi P. Is this the same case when using different browsers? If it is, I would strongly suggest reaching out to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) directly. This doesn't seem to be an issue where the Stack Overflow community could help out on.

Comment: Thanks AL for pointing in the right direction. On chrome I can see the cloud tab, so its a safari browser issue. I reached out to firebase support for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically a web browser problem. This issue happens on Safari where the tab options do not show (if using a Mac). On Windows, using Internet Explorer, the tabs appear but there is web page corruption going on. The way I solved this issue was to download Chrome and the tabs show up perfectly. I used Chrome on my PC and it works... I did not try Chrome on my Mac so I cannot guarantee it works there but in theory it should. I wasted hours on this - I wish google would adhere to web protocols that will work across all web browsers.

Comment: I totally agree!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue ,struggled the whole day.

I suggest you to use the console at "console.developers.google.com",
then click on "credentials" ,
You will be able to see your server key on the right side (make sure you select the project first).

Kind Regards,

Sai Anirudh Sripati.