# Firebase: Is it Possible to do custom notification for the FCM

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to do some customization regarding the FCM of firebase Notification. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Check this link - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream you can create and send custom payload via your servers.

Comment: try this answer on stackoverflow.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37626817/3678308

Comment: what do you mean by custom notification ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KpTSpVh9SfY&feature=youtu.be&t=15m50s The exact explanation on how to do it from Google IO '16 talk

Answer (score 13):

Please, make a difference between Firebase Notifications and Firebase Cloud Messaging. 
https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#notifications-difference

With notifications, you have small manoeuvre space. Key points are:

1. If your app is in foreground, message will not be delivered to notification tray but in your service FireBaseMessagingService so you can do what ever you want with payload/notification.
2. If your app is in background, your notification will be delivered to notification tray (with default look & feel) and FireBaseMessagingService will NOT be called. All payload you send via that push message will be delivered to intent user open via clicking on notification.
3. So, in case of point 2, you can NOT customise notification according your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible Just override onMessageReceived in your service extending FireBaseMessagingService
  You get the data here in this function
Then customize your notification using this data

Comment: If your app is in background, FireBaseMessagingService will not be triggered.

Comment: No it will  be Thats why the service is for. For Background data

Comment: From doc:
If you want to receive notifications when your app is in the foreground, you need to add some message handling logic.
To receive messages, use a service that extends FirebaseMessagingService. 
When your app is in the background, Android directs notification messages to the system tray. 
This includes messages that contain both notification and data payload. In these cases, the notification is delivered to the device's system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras of the intent of your launcher Activity.

Comment: When in Background the app receives the notification payload but not the data payload.

Comment: is it possible to make the service alive either foreground or background. it's like something i'll try to add some wrap withing the service of the firebase..?

Comment: Ya you can surely do that.

Comment: And again from docs:
App behavior when receiving messages that include both notification and data payloads depends on whether the app is in the background or the foreground—essentially, whether or not it is active at the time of receipt.

When in the background, apps receive the notification payload in the notification tray, and only handle the data payload when the user taps on the notification.
When in the foreground, your app receives a message object with both payloads available.
So, FireBaseMessagingService will be useful only when the app is in foreground.

Comment: @Yash Jain I think problem here is that you are addressing Firebase Cloud Messaging, and I am talking about Firebase Notifications.