# Open activity when the firebase notification is recieved without having to click the notification

Tags: android, notifications, background, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-wake-lock

I am building an app which has a calling functionality. So I am getting a notification from server and I have built an activity to show the calling screen in which I have answer and hangup button.

Now I have a question what should I use to start the activity when the app is in background/killed or the phone is locked?

I tried to start activity in the onMessageRecieved function of a FirebaseMessagingService but I think function is not getting called when the app is in background. Because when I tried to debug the same when the app is in background the debug pointer is not triggered and the activity does not open.

The activity opens in the foreground as the notification is recieved but not when the app is in background.

Here is my Service

```
class AppFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    private var pendingIntent: PendingIntent? = null

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        Log.e("get_type_data", remoteMessage!!.data.toString())
        val data = remoteMessage.data
        val myCustomKey = data["notification_data"]

        if(!myCustomKey?.length?.equals(0)!!)
        {
            createNotification(remoteMessage.data)
        }

    }

    private fun createNotification(messageBody: Map<String, String>) {
        val content: String? = messageBody["content"]
        val id: String? = messageBody["id_orders"]
        val type: String? = messageBody["type"]
        var foregroud = false

        try {
            foregroud = ForegroundCheckTask().execute(this).get()
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: ExecutionException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        Log.e("foreground", foregroud.toString())
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val intent: Intent
        val random = Random().nextInt(1000).toString()

            if (foregroud) {
//                intent = Intent("NEW_ORDER")
//                intent.putExtra(Cons.PREF_ORDER_ID, id)
//                sendBroadcast(intent)
                intent = Intent(this, NotificationActivity::class.java)
                intent.addFlags(
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                            or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                )
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this, Integer.valueOf(random)
/* Request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                )
                startActivity(intent)
            } else {
            intent = Intent(this, NotificationActivity::class.java)
                intent.addFlags(
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                            or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                )
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this, Integer.valueOf(random)
/* Request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                )


              /*  intent = Intent(this, NotificationActivity::class.java)
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                        or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, Integer.valueOf(random)
*//* Request code *//*
, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
                startActivity(intent)*/
            }


        if (id != null) {
            val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
            val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(this.resources.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(content)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                val channel = NotificationChannel(
                    id, getString(R.string.app_name),
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
                )
                channel.description = applicationContext.getString(R.string.app_name)
                channel.setShowBadge(true)
                channel.canShowBadge()
                channel.enableLights(true)
                channel.lightColor = applicationContext.getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
                channel.enableVibration(true)
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)

            }
            notificationManager.notify(
                Integer.parseInt(id)
/* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build()
            )
        } else {
            Log.e("randomidforNotif", random)
            val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
            val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, random)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(this.resources.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(content)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                val channel = NotificationChannel(
                    random,
                    getString(R.string.app_name),
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
                )
                channel.description = applicationContext.getString(R.string.app_name)
                channel.setShowBadge(true)
                channel.canShowBadge()
                channel.enableLights(true)
                channel.lightColor = applicationContext.getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
                channel.enableVibration(true)
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)

            }
            notificationManager.notify(
                Integer.parseInt(random)
/* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build()
            )
        }

    }


    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private inner class ForegroundCheckTask : AsyncTask<Context, Void, Boolean>() {

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Context): Boolean? {
            val context = params[0].applicationContext
            return isAppOnForeground(context)
        }

        private fun isAppOnForeground(context: Context): Boolean {
            val activityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
            val appProcesses = activityManager.runningAppProcesses ?: return false
            val packageName = context.packageName
            for (appProcess in appProcesses) {
                if (appProcess.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND && appProcess.processName == packageName) {
                    return true
                }
            }
            return false
        }
    }

    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        super.onNewToken(token)

    }

}
```

I have follwowed this link - [Open activity on firebase notification received in foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39358835/open-activity-on-firebase-notification-received-in-foreground)

Also I tried this - [How to make a screen wake up when a notification is received?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45415774/how-to-make-a-screen-wake-up-when-a-notification-is-received)  ---- to wake up the device

Here is My manifest file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".LauncherActivity">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NotificationActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Note: these actions are notification actions -->
                <action android:name="VIDEO_CALLING" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <!--<service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:targetApi="n">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>-->
        <service
            android:name=".AppFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />

        <!--

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />


        <receiver android:name=".FirebaseDataReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".MyJobIntentService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />


        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"/>

        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.UPLOAD" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have added all the possible permissions and meta deta required.

Please help with the  solution. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Add this line before you show the notification

```
notificationBuilder.setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true);
```

Comment: Does not help. I have added but activity does not get start in when the app is in background. Only I get the notification in system tray.