# Open app upon receiving push-notification

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, push-notification

I'm developing a **WebRTC** app with **React Native**. I've got **Firebase** working, and I can receive notifications on my **Android/iOS devices** whilst in the background or foreground.

Is there any way of when I receive a push-notification to automatically open the app for me, without requiring the user input?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37554274/open-app-on-firebase-notification-received-fcm

Comment: thanks , my bad for not searching 1st. Ill have a look.

Comment: @NileshRathod That question is about FCM and Android only. This one is about React Native which also makes it about iOS. Wouldn't call it a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going for the scenario of an incoming call, it's not the same for both platforms.
For Android, you can start an activity responding to a push notification, but iOS doesn't allow that. You can either send a regular push notification the user might miss, or use [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit) and integrate it with your stuffs.

Unfortunately I don't know good libraries for React Native that can help you with that yet, so it might have to be done natively and bridged to your RN code.

Edit:

Android example - In your native code handling a notification, you can use `context.startActivity(launchIntent);` to launch your app with an incoming call screen.

Comment: My goal is to use Callkit for iOS that will allow me to send pushkit notifications that will wake my app from the background , but in Android I dont have that feature so If possible I want to open my app remotely. Can this be done ?

Comment: Definitely, did it myself for an app. Added some guidance about that.

Comment: Thanks mate, ill have a look to this. Ill share some feedback as soon as I get something to work.

Comment: must I write this code on my android files within react native ?

Comment: You can only do this in Java, maybe you can find some lib to bridge that for you but I don't see a way around it.

Comment: It's working mate , I've used this piece of code.
 `startActivity(launchIntent);`

Comment: is it possible to startActivity on the background ? and only show the activity when app is fully loaded.

Comment: At this point I advise you to mark this question solved and open a new one with more details about what you are facing now

Comment: You need to initiate a new activity while receiving push for incoming call. You can design UI for this screen as per your requirement. Once you receive call from action, you can invoke your react native application from native.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to deviate a little from the code perspective.

But if you are looking forward for external triggers, I would recommend MacroDroid as a potential solution. There are numerous triggers including Notification reads, SMS etc., Macrodroid is available in Play store with trial version limited to five macros per user. Logical validations, loops and much more features to explore.