# FirebaseMessagingService Notification Server (must not open)

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to prohibit opening an activity with **the notification by the FCM server?**

I'm talking about the **notification sent via the manifest**

If the user clicks the notification, by default it open MainActivity.

I just want it to disappear and not open any activity

I try this but not work :

```
 // [START handle_data_extras]
    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
            Object value = getIntent().getExtras().get(key);
            Log.d("TAG", "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);

           if (value.equals(myValue)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Close", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }

        }
```

**Temporary solution :**

open an activity that closes all :

```
  if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
             for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
                 Object value = getIntent().getExtras().get(key);
                 Log.d("TAG", "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
                 if (value.equals(myvaluefirebase)) {
                     Log.d("TAG", "Key value it's OK");
                     Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, **Close.class)**;
                     startActivity(mainIntent);
                     SplashActivity.this.finish();
                     finish();
                 }
             }}
```

Comment: I found this post, it is not possible with the payload : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53129669/desired-activity-not-open-while-clicking-on-notification-fcm

Answer (score 0):

**Set the pending intent like that**

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent  = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(), 0);
            builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

**Also enable setAutoCancel()**

```
  builder.setAutoCancel(true);
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm talking about the notification sent via the manifest