# react-native-firebase - Open app from Headless JS Service / Open app from received notification in background mode

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I read

- [How to handle notification when app in background in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase/44800598#44800598)
- [Open app on firebase notification received (FCM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37554274/open-app-on-firebase-notification-received-fcm)

But these aren't the solution for [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase).

I'm using `react-native-firebase` to handle notifications. In foreground, everything works well. I stuck with background state.

I'm working on a chat project and making 1-to-1 call feature. I push data-notification to clients when they have a call. In iOS, I used CallKit when client received notification, and it worked fine. But in Android I have a problem:
I can show ConnectionService UI for a call, but can't connect to my web socket server because it runs on Headless JS service. So I tried to auto open the app. I want to show a call screen as Skype, and accept/deny the call. (Skype can launch the app when I have a call)

Summary, successful steps:

- Receive call notification in foreground state and show calling screen.
- Receive call notification in background/closed state and show calling screen on iOS.
- Receive call notification in background/closed state on Android.

Stuck here:

- Show calling screen in background/closed on Android ???

**TL;DR - How to launch/run/open Android app from Headless JS Service?**

I dig into react-native-firebase, it catches the notification on `onMessageReceived` and send notification message to Headless JS Service.

`// If the app is in the background we send it to the Headless JS Service
          Intent headlessIntent = new Intent(
            this.getApplicationContext(),
            RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService.class
          );
          headlessIntent.putExtra("message", message);
          this
            .getApplicationContext()
            .startService(headlessIntent);
          HeadlessJsTaskService.acquireWakeLockNow(this.getApplicationContext());`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This library is helpful to open app from background state.
[React Native Launch Application](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-launch-application)

**If your app is quit from background state**

you've to register registerHeadlessTask in index.js like this

```
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask(
'ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingHeadlessTask',
  () => notificationActionHandler,
);
```

and in notificationActionHandler function call libraries function to open app

**If your app is in background you can subscribe this**

```
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(remoteMessage => {
      console.log('setBackgroundMessageHandler', remoteMessage.data);
    })
```