# Android manage long task

Tags: android, performance

I need  a way to plot realtime data on a graph without blocking the UI thread. Reading several posts and articles I have understood that threads aren't the best choice to perform long works (it's an indeterminate update so it could take more than 3-4 minutes). So, what should I use?
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your long task will run while your Activity is running, then you can use an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Else you can use a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: I think I will use a Service but how can I access to the UI thread from the service to update the chart? Bcause I have also read that views should be managed in the UI thread while other computations should be done in a separate thread or in this case in a service

Comment: You can start an Activity from a Service http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456034/how-to-start-an-activity-from-a-service